# React.js - Accessing the elements of an object passed as prop through map function

Tags: reactjs, commerce.js

So I am building an e-commerce app on react using commerce.js

I am passing the cart object(image attached) as props and mapping it using the cart function as below

```
const CartContainer = ({cart}) => {

    
    return(
    
        <div className = "container mx-auto"> 
             <div className="grid grid-rows-3 gap-2 auto-cols-max" >
             {/*Calling the cart item component to render the Cart item one by one*/}
            
              {
                 Object.values(cart).map((item,index) =>
                 (<CartItem item={item} key={index}/>))
             } 

             

            </div>
        </div>
        
        )

}
```

And i am trying to list the elements of the cart as below
but it is not working

```
const Cart = ({item}) =>
{
    
    

    return (
      <div className="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
      <div className="px-1 py-1">
       <div className="text-s">{item.line_items.name}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am calling the cart component this way

```
   <CartContainer cart = {cart}/>
```

How do i access the elements of line_items

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.values() will do exactly as the name implies it will take the values of an object and turn them into an array. You are not passing the item in your Component but you render a Cart for each value.

Comment: got it ... So how do i access the name values in line_items?

Comment: given that line_items is your cart items you can do cart.line_items.map()

Comment: {
                 cart.line_items.map((item) =>
                 (<CartItem item={item} key={item.id}/>))
             } 
gives me TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: It's probably undefined during the first renders. try cart?.line_items?.map()

Comment: No problem! Have fun!